# Can I omit "so" in "so as to do"?

Tags: word-usage

Can I omit "so" in "so as to do"?

like this:

> Post-market clinical studies are not intended to replace the pre-market data necessary to make the decision **as to approve** the device.

here, "as to approve" means "in order to approve"?

If so, is "so" omitted in "so as to approve"?

Comment: Yes, of course. But better is: for a decision to approve the device

Comment: I am dubious that either "the decision as to approve" or "the decision so as to approve" is idiomatic. Any of the following would be idiomatic: "the decision whether or not to approve," "the decision whether to approve," or "the decision to approve." I agree with Lambie that I prefer the third, but the first two are perfectly acceptable. But what makes it hard to discuss the sentence is that it makes no sense. "Approve" what by whom? If the clinicians are approving medical safety and efficacy on the basis of marketing studies, they are criminals. MORE

Comment: CONTINUED What is "pre-market data"? Is that potential revenue estimates or something else being estimated before anything is sold or used on a large scale? I suspect it means research on the potential size of the market, but who knows? Who is making the decision? What business is it of the FDA to look at market research? Probably what is meant is that a business must take into account its market research after clinical trials are successful before deciding to go to market. If that commonplace is meant, say it clearly.

Comment: @Andrew I think that’s the best. Thanks. I don’t know why the writer used as to here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not omit "so", but you can omit both "so" and "as".  Both are extraneous:

> "... necessary to make the decision **to approve** the device."

You can even remove "the decision to" because "approval" is already a kind of decision.

> "... necessary **for approval of** the device."

But this is only about what is considered "good style" in certain contexts, such as business or academia.  In other contexts it's common to add "flowery" words and phrases that effectively *decorate* a sentence without meaning.  "So as to ..." is one example of these, and may be perfectly appropriate for a given audience.

For example, diplomats (in any language) are famous for using ten words when one will do:

> "**In terms of** this treaty between our illustrious nations, **it behooves us to** consider the benefits of the resultant increased mutual felicity, **so as to** improve bilateral commerce and to the enrichment of the general public," etc.